# use of variable causes update to run very slow

Tags: t-sql

I have the following query.

```
  UPDATE t
  SET    UnitsSold = sub.UnitsSold,
  FROM   dbo.table1 t
         JOIN (SELECT s.CustomerKey,
                      s.WeekKey,
                      s.ProductKey,
                      Sum(s.UnitsSold)          AS [UnitsSold],
               FROM   dbo.table2 s
               WHERE  WeekKey >= 335
               GROUP  BY s.WeekKey,
                         s.CustomerKey,
                         s.ProductKey) AS sub
           ON sub.WeekKey = t.WeekKey
              AND sub.CustomerKey = t.CustomerKey
              AND sub.ProductKey = t.ProductKey
```

It runs like a champ.  About 2 seconds.  Then when try and make it dynamic via the following.

```
      DECLARE @StartWeekKey AS INT 
        SET @StartWeekKey = 335

  UPDATE t
  SET    UnitsSold = sub.UnitsSold,
  FROM   dbo.table1 t
         JOIN (SELECT s.CustomerKey,
                      s.WeekKey,
                      s.ProductKey,
                      Sum(s.UnitsSold)          AS [UnitsSold],
               FROM   dbo.table2 s
               WHERE  WeekKey >= @StartWeekKey
               GROUP  BY s.WeekKey,
                         s.CustomerKey,
                         s.ProductKey) AS sub
           ON sub.WeekKey = t.WeekKey
              AND sub.CustomerKey = t.CustomerKey
              AND sub.ProductKey = t.ProductKey
```

All of a sudden, it's super slow.

any good ideas?

EDIT:
Probalby should have mentioned this, but this is contained in a stored proc.

Added the @StartWeekKey as a parameter to the proc and it goes back to running in a few seconds.

Comment: What are the *used/actual* execution plans in both cases? For "super slow" I'd expect them to not look the same; it might have to do with a heuristic chosen.

Comment: As pst says you need to look at the query plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems to have been asked several times before and the general answer is that it has to do with statistics.

Try:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS table_or_indexed_view_name
```

to get your statistics up to date and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't unheard of when different parameters have *very* different distributions, thus different good plans. What can happen is that the query gets executed for a given value, and then that plan gets cached and re-used inappropriately for a different value.

If this is the case (just a guess - I can't run your query to check!) then try adding:

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@StartWeekKey UNKNOWN))
```

to the end of the query.

---

Another thought: is `WeekKey` actually an `int` ? is this some kind of mass type conversion issue?

---

I have no way of checking these; if I'm miles off the track, let me know so I can remove an unhelpful answer.